# How to populate a TreeViewControl with hierarchy level?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have a TreeView Control (that should look like this)

[image]

But I don't know how to populate it with my query:

```
SELECT T.TableName, C.Column_Name FROM Information_Schema.Tables T
INNER JOIN Information_Schema.Columns C
 ON T.TableName= C.TableName
WHERE T.TableName IN('BASE_TABLE', 'BASE TABLE')
ORDER BY 1, C.Ordinal_Position
```

Can anyone help me please...

Thanks.

**Edit**
This is what I tried, but just the table names...

```
private void PopulateTreeView()
{
    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
    try
    {
        using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=" + connString))
        {            
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES";
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            // Don't know what's next...
        }
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(x.GetBaseException().ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: LINQ to SQL? LINQ to EF?

Comment: @Ani: I'm getting tired of asking that question everytime.

Comment: @yonan: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm confused - what is the problem here? the `TreeView`? or the LINQ? The "This is what I tried" covers neither the `TreeView` **not** the LINQ...

Comment: I'm sorry if I can't express my thoughts clearly, not so good with english

Comment: what I'm trying to achieve is somewhat like in the server explorer of the vs... but only the table names and under it is the columns of the table. just like in my illustration above.

Comment: @yonan2236 - so... what has that got to do with LINQ?

Comment: I'm just wondering if LINQ can solve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a non-LINQ answer that does something simmilar:

```
using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = @"
SELECT T.TABLE_NAME, C.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
ON T.TABLE_NAME= C.TABLE_NAME
WHERE T.TABLE_NAME IN('BASE_TABLE', 'BASE TABLE')
ORDER BY 1, C.ORDINAL_POSITION";
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        string lastTable = null;
        TreeNode tableNode = null;
        while (reader.Read()) { 
            if (lastTable != reader.GetString(0)) {
                lastTable = reader.GetString(0);
                tableNode = new TreeNode(lastTable);
                myTree.Nodes.Add(tableNode);
            }
            tableNode.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(reader.GetString(1)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hehe.. I just edited some of your code and it's now working. I already posted the working code, and changed the title of this question. Thanks sir...

Answer (score 0):

btw, never never use `MessageBox` on a server ;p

The core query *using LINQ-to-SQL* is something like:

```
using (var ctx = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
    string[] names = {"BASE_TABLE", "BASE TABLE"};
    var qry = (from table in ctx.Tables
               where names.Contains(table.TableName)
               join column in ctx.Columns on table.TableName equals column.TableName
               orderby table.TableName, column.ColumnName
               select new { table.TableName, column.ColumnName }).ToList();
    foreach (var pair in qry.GroupBy(pair => pair.TableName))
    {
        TreeNode tableNode = new TreeNode(pair.Key);
        myTree.Nodes.Add(tableNode);
        foreach (var col in pair)
        {
            tableNode.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(col.ColumnName));
        }
    }
}
```

assuming a **hand-crafted** DBML (since the designer filters these tables), along the lines of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Database Name="YourDatabase" Class="DataClasses1DataContext" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/linqtosql/dbml/2007">
  <Connection Mode="WebSettings" ConnectionString="YourConnectionString" SettingsObjectName="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings" SettingsPropertyName="YourConnectionStringPropertyName" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <Table Name="INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES" Member="Tables">
    <Type Name="Table">
      <Column Name="TABLE_NAME" Member="TableName" Type="System.String" DbType="nvarchar(128) NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
    </Type>
  </Table>
  <Table Name="INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS" Member="Columns">
    <Type Name="Column">
      <Column Name="TABLE_NAME" Member="TableName" Type="System.String" DbType="nvarchar(128) NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="COLUMN_NAME" Member="ColumnName" Type="System.String" DbType="nvarchar(128) NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="ORDINAL_POSITION"  Member="OrdinalPosition" Type="System.Int32" DbType="int NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
    </Type>
  </Table>
</Database>
```

Comment: ok thanks sir... this is not exactly what I want but I can use your idea. I'll post my answer as soon as I get it working...

Answer (score 0):

This is the working answer. I just edited some lines from Sir Gravell's code

```
private void PopulateTreeView()
{
    treeView1.Nodes.Clear();

    using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=" + connString))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT T.TABLE_NAME, C.COLUMN_NAME
                            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS T INNER JOIN
                            Information_Schema.Columns AS C ON T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
                            WHERE T.TABLE_TYPE IN('BASE_TABLE', 'BASE TABLE', 'TABLE')
                            ORDER BY T.TABLE_NAME, C.ORDINAL_POSITION";
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            string lastTable = null;
            TreeNode tableNode = null;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (lastTable != reader.GetString(0))
                {
                    lastTable = reader.GetString(0);
                    tableNode = new TreeNode(lastTable);
                    treeView1.Nodes.Add(tableNode);
                }
                tableNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(reader.GetString(1)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have removed the sort-order, this probably won't work correctly. The `ORDER BY` is critical to the code I posted. Also, my use if upper-case `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` was deliberate, as databases can be (and often are) set in case-sensitive mode. Wrong-cased object- or column-names will not work.